# Espnow on esp8266 micropython OSError: -3

Tags: esp8266, esp32, micropython, oserror, esp-now

I was recantly experimenting with espnow in micropython. Sudenly I rann Into A Problem wenn trying to run this code:

```
import network, espnow, time

wlan_sta = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan_sta.active(True)

e = espnow.ESPNow()
e.active(True)

peer = b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'     # MAC
e.add_peer(peer)
while True:
    e.send(peer, "ESP")
    time.sleep(1.1)  # Sekunden
```

i get the Error OSError: -3

The Code worked on my Esp32 but not on the 8266 no clue why.
I tried reflashing my esp but that did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://micropython-glenn20.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/espnow.html) you need to call `wla_sta.disconnect()` after setting `wlan_sta.active(True)`. This is the example from the docs:

```
import network
import espnow

# A WLAN interface must be active to send()/recv()
sta = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)  # Or network.AP_IF
sta.active(True)
sta.disconnect()   # For ESP8266

e = espnow.ESPNow()
e.active(True)
peer = b'\xbb\xbb\xbb\xbb\xbb\xbb'   # MAC address of peer's wifi interface
e.add_peer(peer)

e.send("Starting...")       # Send to all peers
for i in range(100):
    e.send(peer, str(i)*20, True)
    e.send(peer, b'end')    # The example in the docs is missing the `peer` argument.
```

If I run that example as written (well, correcting the second call to `e.send` as shown in the above code) and the corresponding receiver code, it all works just fine on a pair of esp8266's running `v1.19.1-espnow-6-g44f65965b`.

---

**Update** I think your problem is that the esp8266 may not support the broadcast address. While the documentation suggests that the esp8266 should be able to **send** to the broadcast address:

> All active ESP-Now clients will receive messages sent to their MAC address
> and all devices (except ESP8266 devices) will also receive messages sent to
> the broadcast MAC address (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff') or any multicast MAC
> address.
>
> **All ESP-Now devices (including ESP8266 devices) can also send messages to the
> broadcast MAC address or any multicast MAC address.**

It appears that this isn't the case. I'm able to use the example code from the docs when operating in unicast mode, but attempting to call `e.add_peer` with the broadcast address results in the same error you've reported.

I've opened [issue #11](https://github.com/glenn20/micropython/issues/11) with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is still not working for me. I think there might be a problem with the build i have. A friend of mine made a flash of micropython with intigrated espnow for me because i have no clue how to do thath. Maybe that is the problem. What Library or build are you using?

Comment: Hi, sorry that the first answer wasn't on target; I hadn't noticed at first that you were attempting to send to the broadcast address. See my update; it looks like that isn't possible right now with esp8266 devices.

Answer (score -1):

In Conclusion you can say that It IS posibille to use ESPnow on the esp 8266 in SingelCasting Mode but not in MultiCasting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).